# Can sentences be grammatical if commas are added?

Tags: commas

> 1. "He with the hat knows her with the scarf"
> 2. "He, with the hat, knows her, with the scarf"
> 3. I pity them who lost their money on gambling.
> 4. I pity them, who lost their money on gambling.

I know 1,3 are wrong, but if I add commas in 1 and 3, are 2 and 4 correct?
To me, without commas added, 1 and 3 sound wrong. I  mean 1 and 3 seem to convey very awkward meanings.

In this case, I think commas must be needed because "he", "her", "them" are already definite in the context, so those parts set apart by commas are not essential information. For this reason, if commas are added, I think 2 and 4 are, at least, grammatically correct, although there's more-natural wordings than 2 and 4.

Is my thinking correct?

Comment: Why do you think 1 and 3 are wrong? Because they sound awkward? To me, 2 sounds more awkward than 1.

Comment: Now 3 is wrong, but only because "them who" is ungrammatical, not because of lack of commas.

Comment: @Mr Lister As I already said, without commas, to me, 1 and 3 don't make much sense because as for 1, it sounds like "When he is with the hat and she is with the scarf, he knows her", but if "he" and "she" are changed to "the man" and "the woman" or commas are added, the sentence seems to make sense, although it sounds still awkward as you see the 2nd sentence.

Comment: I disagree. But maybe that's a matter of opinion; let's wait for what the experts have to say.

Comment: @Mr Lister Yeah, but I would like to know at least the reason you disagree with me on what point.

Comment: SinK - @MrLister is correct, for the simple reason that there is nothing wrong with the punctuation of 1 and 3.  Focusing just on sentence 1, a native speaker reading that sentence will automatically parse it as "X knows Y", regardless of what values are slotted into X and Y.  The subject-verb-object is probably the simplest structure in the English.  We therefore automatically parse the sentence as "[the tall man with the hat and purple shirt] knows [the woman with the scarf and the red shoes]."   No punctuation is required.

Comment: @SinK - Also, as Mr Lister points out, sentence 3 is not correct.  It should read "I pity **those** who lost their money on gambling."

Comment: Further, although the punctation of sentence 2 may not be technically incorrect, it comes across as awkward and strange.  It's the sort of sentence you might write in poem for dramatic effect, but it would not be appropriate in a newspaper article or a legal report. If you'd written sentence 2 in a book, a reputable editor would have removed all the commas.  As a general principle of good writing in English, commas should be used only where they are either (a) necessary for the reader to understand the author's intent correctly, or (b) for poetic effect.

Comment: All of the sentences are grammatical. Whether they are natural or stylistically acceptable is something entirely different. They can only be considered *wrong* if they end up meaning something you don't want them to mean. But you haven't said what you want them to mean, so there's no way of knowing if they are *wrong* or not.